# Getting a link to open in a new window on Android 2

Tags: jquery, android, html, jquery-mobile

Using jquerymobile HTML etc, Android3,4 have tabbed browsing so when I mark my links up with `target="_blank"` they open in new window but on Android 2 it doesn't work. Is it actually posibble?

It's just otherwise the user when returning to the app has to start all over again lol

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var url;
    url = $("a").attr('href');
    $("a").attr("onclick", "window.open('"+url+"'); return false;");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: one of this issues about opening in a new window in gingerbread is, to actually navigate back to your existing window is something thats pretty complicated from a user-interface perspective. You need to click on the settings button, choose windows, then choose your existing window. its just way less intuitive than A3, A4, iPhone etc

Answer (score 0):

Using the .on() function instead of .click() reduces DOMEvents and will help with page speed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', 'a[target="_blank"]', function(e) {
        window.open($(this).attr('href'));
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```