# How to load a new Window using HTML url? in Android

Tags: android, css, url, android-intent, android-browser

I have a HTML property to load

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
```

I load this to my Android Screen using

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, my_url, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8", null);
```

But when I try clicking on it the link doesn't take me to a new window but opens in the current window, even though i specified `target="_blank"` in my HTML.

How can i make  it load the link in a new window in Android??

Comment: I think you mean "in your HTML", not "CSS" -> `target="_blank"`

Comment: @Patrick yes sorry HTML, I will edit the question, but yes do you know how open link in android?

Comment: Do you want to start a new activity or open the browser?

Comment: @PatrickMlr hi sir,  if it contains target="_blank" then yes Open the browser

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355280/getting-a-link-to-open-in-a-new-window-on-android-2

Comment: For native Android. Thanks anyways I found the answer @PatrickMlr https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187714/android-open-target-blank-links-in-webview-with-external-browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in this link [Android - Open target _blank links in WebView with external browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187714/android-open-target-blank-links-in-webview-with-external-browser)

To Summarize:

```
    wv.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean dialog, boolean userGesture, android.os.Message resultMsg)
    {
        WebView.HitTestResult result = view.getHitTestResult();
        String data = result.getExtra();
        Context context = view.getContext();
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(data));
        context.startActivity(browserIntent);
        return false;
    }
});
```